# Call and SMS counter in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to monitor the call and sms usage in the iphone like how much time calling take place to whom, when , how long etc. Same in the case of SMS.
After a bit of googling i found that "Consume" is the application that does the similar task what i want.

After a lot of research i found the solution to read the sqlite db? but is it the right way to approach this?
Did apple allowed this type of application?

Anyone can explain how "Consume" works or how can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not **completely** clear how Consume works, but there are some details on their site that suggest the answer.

From http://bjango.com/help/consume/gettingstarted/

> Please note that most mobile phone carriers require that you register for online services before you can monitor your usage using a web browser or Consume...

From http://bjango.com/help/consume/problems/

> Quite a few providers require you to register for ‘online services’. In short, this means you need to sign up to be able to view your account details and status online. Consume can’t grab the info it needs if you haven’t registered.

It **seems** that Consume is getting the information from mobile phone carrier sites rather than looking it up locally. That's not surprising, because there's very little chance of Apple approving an app that accessed the phone's records. Third party apps aren't supposed to get direct local access. If you site for jailbroken phones, that's a different story.